# DataTables warning

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to display table in asp.net using [this](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) example
The problem is that it shows the following error:

> DataTables warning: table id=datalistTable - Requested unknown
>   parameter '1' for row 0. For more information about this error, please
>   see http://datatables.net/tn/4

```
<asp:DataList ID="datalist2" runat="server" 
        onitemcommand="Datalist1_ItemCommand"  
        oneditcommand="Datalist1_EditCommand" oncancelcommand="datalist1_CancelCommand" 
        onupdatecommand="datalist1_UpdateCommand" 
        ondeletecommand="datalist2_DeleteCommand">
        <HeaderTemplate>     
            <table id="datalistTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Tema</th>            
                    <th>Keywords</th>
                    <th>Data Publikimit</th>
                    <th>Veprimi</th>
                </tr> 
             </thead>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate> 
         <tbody>            
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Id") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblTema" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Tema") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="LabelKeywords" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Keywords") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="LabelKategoria" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Data_Publikimit") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                     <td><asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Select"/>
                     <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" /></td>
                </tr> 
        </tbody>             
        </ItemTemplate>        
        <FooterTemplate>
        </table>      
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

codebehind

```
public partial class DataList : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringDatabase"].ConnectionString;
    PagedDataSource adsource;
    int pos;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                                     
                   if(!IsPostBack)
                    {
                        this.ViewState["vs"] = 0;

                    }
                    pos = (int)this.ViewState["vs"];
                    Bind();                       

        }
        public void Bind() 
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from artikulli", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adsource = new PagedDataSource();
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            adsource.PageSize = 3;
            adsource.AllowPaging = true;
            adsource.CurrentPageIndex = pos;
            adsource.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            btnfirst.Enabled = !adsource.IsFirstPage;
            btnprevious.Enabled = !adsource.IsFirstPage;
            btnlast.Enabled = !adsource.IsLastPage;
            btnnext.Enabled = !adsource.IsLastPage;
            datalist2.DataSource = adsource;
            datalist2.DataBind();
        }
        protected void Datalist1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Datalist1_EditCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("Edit"))
            {
                Label lblId = e.Item.FindControl("lblId") as Label;
                string id = lblId.Text;
                Response.Redirect("EditArtikull.aspx?id=" + id);
            }
        }
        protected void datalist1_CancelCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            datalist2.EditItemIndex = -1;
            Bind();
        }
        protected void btnfirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pos = 0;
            Bind();
        }

        protected void btnprevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pos = (int)this.ViewState["vs"];
            pos -= 1;
            this.ViewState["vs"] = pos;
            Bind();
        }

        protected void btnnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pos = (int)this.ViewState["vs"];
            pos += 1;
            this.ViewState["vs"] = pos;
            Bind();
        }

        protected void btnlast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pos = adsource.PageCount - 1;
            Bind();
        }
        protected void datalist2_DeleteCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            Label lblId = e.Item.FindControl("lblId") as Label;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "Delete from artikulli where id=@id";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 11).Value = lblId.Text;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            Bind();

        }
}
```

Comment: http://datatables.net/tn/4 seems pretty thorough on the subject.  Did you go through all those steps?

Comment: yes I did. And I think the problem is that it doesn't finds the tr and td inside <ItemTemplate> but I don't know what to do :(

Comment: @paqogomez I would be truly grateful if you take a look at my code an tell me what is wtong

Comment: Be ware that DataTables.Net just had a massive update with breaking changes. What version are you using?

Comment: version of what? visualstudio 2010

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach is a misc of AJAX with pure JavaScript with jQuery combined with a handler to it than a misc of asp.net controls with js library, sometimes direct coding with HTML/JavaScript is the simpliest way to achieve the solution

You really need to use Datalist?

EDIT:
In your case I can only think in a change of `<asp:DataList>` for a `<asp:Repeater>` for the easiness of change and the plug and play functionality

so maintain all the inner code of your datalist ASPX code and change the element for `<asp:Repeater>` and you're done.

Your problem is that `<asp:DataList>` is already a `<table>`, so in your case you're inserting a table inside another, and the format of datalist renderized code do not include the header of `<table>` in a `<thead>` but directly as a  row, and exists another problem with "ghost" rows that `<asp:DataList>` creates on renderized code.

So if I was you, I would go with `<asp:Repeater>` at least accurately in your case

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datalistTable').dataTable();
} );

Comment: That's the only js and libraries as are in example that I have given by link

Comment: I want to know is, if is it possible to integrate jquery DataTable with DataList??

Comment: I have used DataList everywhere, i don't have much time to change this. I am new at this language and I really need this table paginationa and sortable but at the same time I want to addapt with template or use jquery plugin. Please tell me how to do it without changign the hole application

Comment: post some codebehind code to make a test possible for us, without it is more complicated

Comment: just edited my question. In codebehind I also added the code for table pagination, but I really don't like it this way. Pls if u are there take a look

Comment: can you guarantee that at least the data is filled on the page? what I mean is, if you remove all the JS of DataTables.js of your page and for instance run all in pure asp.net code, all work well?

Comment: Tested here, unfortunately with Datalist it's more complicated, cause the <asp:DataList> 
it's already an Table in it's own basic structure, the best approach I have is change for a <asp:Repeater>, and it's purely plug and play, you don't need to change anything in your HTML code, only the change of type of element

Comment: pls edit my code, i would be grateful because I am new at asp.net

Comment: look at my edited answer, remember, getting dirty with the code and  problems that we have, this is the way to learn how to solve by ourselves, and don't forget to try googling always that you don't know how is the best way to achieve an objective programming, because there's always a lot of ways to get there, but always have the "best practices" method too, and this is the best way

Comment: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater' does not have a public property named 'oneditcommand'.

Comment: there's a equivalent 'onitemcommand="datalist2_ItemCommand"' that you can use

Comment: could you tell me which is the equivalent

Comment: is the same, as I mentioned, have you tried at least to find a way to make the repater work? and please, if you found the solution with my help, mark  my answer.